# Two Factor Authentication code is not match in Staging/Production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, imagemagick, minimagick, two-factor-authentication

I have setup **Two Factor Authentication** in my Rails4 app. Everything works fine in my development environment, but failed in Staging environment. My **Staging** environment is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running NGINX web server. I already have `ImageMagick 6.7.7-10` installed. While my **Development** environment is macOS High Sierra, and I have `ImageMagick 7.0.6-7` installed and running THIN web server.

Rubygems:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
gem 'devise-two-factor', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.1'
gem 'rqrcode-rails3', '~> 0.1.7'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.5'
```

The QRCode is rendered on **Staging**, but it looks different from **Development**. I'm not sure if this is a case. One more thing is that, the QRCode can be scanned by Google Authenticator app, but when I verify the code, it is failed. In **Staging**, I've checked `user.current_otp` in rails console, it is never match with the code I have scanned. But in **Development**, I scan the QRCode, I get the match code as I perform `user.current_otp` in my rails console.

I render QRCode as an svg image.

```
<%= raw RQRCode::render_qrcode(current_user.otp_provisioning_uri(current_user.email, issuer: "2FA App"), :svg, level: :l, unit: 2) %>
```

I would be really appreciate for your help and provide more detail if you like.

Comment: Just a point. ImageMagick 7 uses magick and not convert as in IM 6. So your Rmagick may not understand convert if using IM 7. Also there have been changes to imagemagick since 6.7.7.10. That version is over 200 versions old and was undergoing colorspace and grayscale changes at the time. I would suggest you upgrade if possible.

Comment: I did try upgrading IM 6 to IM 7, but Ubuntu 14.04 states that my IM 6 is already the latest version.

Comment: I think Ruby probably does not understand IM 7. You should keep only IM 6. Just note that Linux distributions generally are way behind in their patches to ImageMagick. The best way to know is to see what the patch date is associated with your IM release number. You should check with the Ruby developers whether it is compatible with IM 7.

Comment: Have you confirmed both the Staging and Development servers as well as your device you scan the QR on all have their times synced to a NTP server? I am guessing your Staging server is a few minutes (or ever just more than 30 seconds) out of sync.

Comment: @fmw42 I've just figured that the cause is not about IM version. And, I guess it would be caused by the different time zone between my local and staging server as David's mentioned.

Comment: @DavidVanDeMeer You're right. My local and staging server time zones are different. I'm still googling how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed in the comments above you need to set up NTP op the Staging Server and sync the Time as well as possibly sync the Time in the Google Authenticator app on your phone:

To Install NTP on Ubuntu:

Disable timesyncd:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp no
```

Verify that timesyncd is disabled:

```
timedatectl
```

Install ntpd:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Check that ntpd is running:

```
sudo ntpq -p
```

Check the Date and Time:

```
date
```

Compare the minutes and seconds with some site links this: https://www.timeanddate.com/

Sync time on Android / iOS Google Authenticator App:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en

Scroll to the very bottom section: "My Google Authenticator codes aren’t working (Android)"